# Give an example of a relation $R$ that is a total injective function from a set $A$ to itself but is not bijection?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

Give an example of a relation $R$ that is a total injective function from a set $A$ to itself but is not bijection.

This is problem from  Mathematics for Computer Science([chrome-extension://ikhdkkncnoglghljlkmcimlnlhkeamad/pdf-viewer/web/viewer.html?file=https%3A%2F%2Fcourses.csail.mit.edu%2F6.042%2Fspring17%2Fmcs.pdf](http://chrome-extension://ikhdkkncnoglghljlkmcimlnlhkeamad/pdf-viewer/web/viewer.html?file=https%3A%2F%2Fcourses.csail.mit.edu%2F6.042%2Fspring17%2Fmcs.pdf)) in page 126

Comment: You just want an injective function from $A$ to itself that isn't surjective? Or are you asking for something else?

Comment: $n\mapsto n+1$ on $\mathbb N$. Or am I misunderstanding things?

Comment: I am sorry, there are something wrong with my markdown edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R = \{ (n,2n) | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ will do.  I'll leave it to you to prove it is total, injective, but not bijective.

Comment: Just a question out of curiosity, Bram: what does "total" mean here?

Comment: @Vera A relation $R \subseteq A \times B$ is total if every $a \in A$ has an image $b \in B$ under $R$, i.e. it doesn't leave any $a$ undefined.